# I am using foreach to iterate over an array and send sms to each nos,but not able to do so.It send to only a single

Tags: php, laravel-5

The 2nd foreach should send to each new_token->mob .but it sends to one and then stops.what am doing wrong?

My code is :

```
foreach($new_tokens as $new_tokenss) 
{ 
   foreach($new_tokenss as $new_token) 
   {

            $message = "Message";
            $message_encoded = urlencode($message);
            $postData = array(
                'authkey' => \Config::get('procedures.msg91.authKey'),
                'mobiles' => $new_token->mob,
                'message' => $message_encoded,
                'sender' => \Config::get('procedures.msg91.senderId'),
                'route' => \Config::get('procedures.msg91.route')
            );

            $curl = new \anlutro\cURL\cURL;
            $curl->post(\Config::get('procedures.msg91.api_url'), $postData);
            return 'New emergency patient';
   }

}
```

Comment: Try to debug your application.

Comment: Tried that if i remove the message part then i am able to store that in an array as $record []=$new_token->mob. and get all the mobile nos but with the message part i am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
    return 'New emergency patient';
```

This like makes the function to return the above mentioned value and thus break the for loop.

Comment: without return also same issue

Comment: try printing something in forloop. This way you can see if your for loopis being executed only once or multiple times.

Comment: yes forloop works ok .I tried doing  $record []=$new_token->mob and count the $records later, shows all the mobile nos.But when i put the msg body it shows only one time.

Comment: try printing something instead of return statement. For debugging purpose. and check if it is being printed only once.